# Error reading PDB file using while loop and $_

Tags: perl

I am not very familiar with Perl, but am trying to get some old code written by someone else to work. The objective of the code is to run a program called stride on input files that end in file.pdb. It should grab all .pdb files in the directory, run stride, and create output files. I know that the stride program works standalone, but I get the following error when I try to run the code: "Error reading PDB file _file.pdb". In other similar code, I get the more specific error "Global symbol "$original_filename" requires explicit package name". I think I have narrowed the issue down to the code's use of $_. I would appreciate any help on why this code no longer works and what an updated version would look like. Thanks. (Note, the use strict and warnings is hashed out because it was not part of the original code).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#use strict;
#use warnings;


while(<>){
    chomp;
        my $input = "$_"."_file.pdb";
        my $output = "$_".".stride";
        my $command = "stride "."$input -f"."$output"." -cA";
        system($command);
}
```

Comment: How are you running this code?

Comment: That code cannot raise the error `Global symbol "$original_filename" requires explicit package name` because no such variable exists in it. Most likely, whatever script (`stride` ?) you're calling raises that error. Check whether that `system()` command works stand-alone.

Comment: I am running it from a terminal using perl run_stride.pl.

Comment: Print out that `$command` to see exactly what you are running by `system`. Then copy-paste it (from the output of this program) into the terminal and run it by hand.

Comment: What input are you giving it?

Comment: Is this .. a complete program? Why are `strict` and `warnings` commented out?

Comment: If the directory has files with `.pdb`, as you seem to say, then your `$input` ends up being `name.pdg_file.pdb` (once you replace `while (<>)` with `for (@ARGV)`). Is that intended?

Comment: No, I'll try to explain a bit more. In the working directory I have several files that start with a 4 letter PDB codes, then have _file.pdb after them, for example 1ALY_file.pdb. The perl script should one-at-a-time, grab the file name and call the program stride to run it. I can get stride to run in the terminal on an individual file simply by typing stride 1ALY_file.pdb (using the above example). The default output for stride is just to print it to the terminal window, so that's what I see. The script should generate a new file with the name 1ALY_file.pdboutput.

Comment: @curd  Thank you for more information. Please add `print "$command\n";` before `system` and see what it prints (that is what then gets run -- or attempted).  I assume for this that you implemented the change from my answer.

Comment: It's not printing anything. I added it like this:
        my $command = "stride "."$input -f"."$output"." -cA";
        print "$command\n";
        system($command);
}

Comment: If I type perl run_stride.pl 1ALY_file.pdb in the terminal I get the following:          stride 1ALY_file.pdb_file.pdb -f1ALY_file.pdb.stride -cAError reading PDB file 1ALY_file.pdb_file.pdb

Answer (score 2):

The phrase `while (<>)` reads every *line* from all files given on the command line.

The code appears to work with file names, which are in `@ARGV`, so the simplest change is

```
foreach (@ARGV) { ... }
```

and now `$_` in the loop body has one filename at a time (or whatever is supplied to the program on the command line).

See about the "null filehandle" `<>` in [I/O operators in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators)

Comment: Maybe  it's a carriage return at the end of `$_` that is not removed by `chomp`?

Comment: @Corion Right, that could be one thing. I'd first guess that the code author misunderstood what `while (<>)` does?

Comment: Thanks for your response. This seems somewhat better, because the error is gone, however, it still isn't generating output files called output_file.pdb.

Comment: @curd We have _no information_ to figure out what that is about. For the first step, I recommend: add print statements to see what you actually have there -- for instance, print `$command` before `system` and review it. If it looks fine then copy-paste it so to run it manually in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need perl for your task?
Try this shell command:

```
for name in file1 file2 file3; do stride ${name}_file.pdb -f ${name}.stride -cA; done
```

Or

```
for name in ./*_file.pdb; do stride "${name}" -f "${name:0:-9}.stride" -cA; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help! This appears to work now if I run it from command line with perl run_stride.pl *_file.pdb:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


foreach(@ARGV){
    chomp;
        my $input = "$_";
        my $output = "$_".".stride";
        my $command = "stride "."$input -f"."$output"." -cA";
        system($command);
}
```